# React-Meteor "cannot read property X of undefined" from another page

Tags: javascript, meteor, reactjs

I am building an app with `React-Meteor`, and having problems with the randomness of its behaviour. When using parts of the app, I get an error that says:

> Cannot read property X of undefined

but the X (and the render of it) is from a different page, usually from the page I was in before, sometimes from a lot of other pages. However, if I refresh and try, it will produce no errors.

The error when only one shows is as follows:

```
Exception from Tracker recompute function:
debug.js:41 TypeError: Cannot read property 'jobId' of undefined
    at React.createClass.getMeteorData (user.jsx:209)
    at meteor-data-mixin.jsx:89
    at Tracker.Computation._compute (tracker.js:323)
    at new Tracker.Computation (tracker.js:211)
    at Object.Tracker.autorun (tracker.js:562)
    at meteor-data-mixin.jsx:76
    at Object.Tracker.nonreactive (tracker.js:589)
    at MeteorDataManager.calculateData (meteor-data-mixin.jsx:75)
    at ReactMeteorData.componentWillUpdate (meteor-data-mixin.jsx:22)
    at ReactCompositeComponentMixin._performComponentUpdate (ReactCompositeComponent.js:535)
```

In some cases, multiple of these will show, from a couple of other pages, with different Xs.

This is the code of the page I am on:

```
Template.addNotification.onRendered(function() {
    ReactDOM.render(<AddNotification />,
                    document.getElementById("addNotification"));
});

AddNotification = React.createClass({
    addNotification: function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        notificationInfo = {
            message: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.msg).value,
            notifType: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.notifType).value,
            user: ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.user).value
        };
        Meteor.call("addNotification", notificationInfo);
    },
    addBunch: function(evt) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        Meteor.call("addBunch", Meteor.userId());
    },
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <div>Message:<input type="text" ref="msg"/></div>
                <div>Type:<input type="text" ref="notifType"/></div>
                <div>User:<input type="text" ref="user"/></div>

                <button onClick={this.addNotification}>Add</button>

                <button onClick={this.addBunch}>
                    Or, add a bunch to current</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
});
```

You can see that I am not even calling anything that needs `jobId` in this page.

Comment: It's a really common error in js - particularly in meteor apps. Have a look at [this post](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards).

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply. Had a read and was wondering when you say " While iron-router goes a long way towards solving the problem, it doesn't fix the case where the data simply isn't there.", do you mean the case where the data isn't there YET, or just that there is no data, expectedly?

Comment: I mean the case where there just isn't any data in the db.

Comment: This is great, I managed to add guard expressions and it solved the issue. Thank you!

Comment: How do I take your solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a case where you need a [guard](http://dweldon.silvrback.com/guards). Have a look at the source of the error and guard it with something like:

```
obj && obj.jobId
```

Where `obj` is the potentially undefined object.